# Grouping data with sum

Tags: linq

I have the following list:

```
 mat.Add(new Material() { ID = 1, ProdName = "Cylinder", Weight=23, Discontinued='N'  });
 mat.Add(new Material() { ID = 2, ProdName = "Gas", Weight = 25, Discontinued='N' });
mat.Add(new Material() { ID = 3, ProdName = "Match", Weight = 23, Discontinued='N' });
```

I want a result as:

```
2 Products have Weight 23 and Discontinued N
1 Product have Weigth 25 Discontinued N
```

Comment: How about showing your attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you're actually grouping by - is it both weight *and* the discontinued status? If so, you can just do:

```
var query = mat.GroupBy(material => 
                        new { material.Weight, material.Discontinued });

foreach (var result in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} products have {1}", result.Count(), result.Key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
.GroupBy(re => new { re.Weight, re.Discontinued })
           .Select(grp => new { CXXX = group.Key, Count = grp.Count()
```

Comment: It would help if you kept to the same properties as in your question. And what does this have to do with summing in the first place (as per your title)?

Answer (score 0):

"just" group by Weight and Discontinued.

something like :
var result = mat.GroupBy(a=>new{a.Weight,a.Discontinued}).Select(b=>new b.Key.Weight,b.Key.Discontinued,Count = b.Count()});